# Ejecutar código PHP al abrir ventana Modal de Boostrap

Tags: php, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente modal:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>Producto añadido a su lista de interés!</p>
            <p>Puede seguir navegando para añadir más productos a su lista o bien verla ahora mismo <a href="lista.php">haciendo click aquí</a> o verla más tarde en el menú superior.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como puedo hacer para que al abrir el modal se ejecute un codigo php ?? Lo que intento es que cuando le den a un botón se abra ese modal. Y a la vez se cree una cookie

Answer (score 1):

No se puede hazlo con AJAX

```
function postAjax(url, data, success) {
    var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
        function (k) {
            return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k])
        }
    ).join('&');
    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = e => {
        if (xhr.readyState > 3 && xhr.status == 200) success(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(params);
    return xhr;
}
```

Esta es una función que te enviará la data a una pagina php y lo que hagas echo con PHP será envíado de regreso, un ejemplo de esto sería

// example request

```
postAjax('http://foo.bar/', 'p1=1&p2=Hello+World', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

// example request with data object

```
postAjax('http://foo.bar/', {
    p1: 1,
    p2: 'Hello World'
}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Y de ahí solo hace falta que hagas un evento en click al botón que hará aparecer el modal ejecute la consulta y regresas los datos y luego haces lo que quiera que quieras hacer